# Eve REST Api Server on Azure HTTP Connectivity

Tags: python, azure, rest, server, eve

I'm trying to deploy a server to Azure to provide a RESTful API. I've set up the VM, deployed the code below, but after I run the app in the cloud my HTTP requests hang.

I have this code for the app

```
from eve import Eve
import logging
import logging.handlers

def log_every_get(resource, request, payload):
    # custom INFO-level message is sent to the log file
    app.logger.info('GET Processed')

app = Eve()
app.on_post_GET += log_every_get

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # enable logging to 'app.log' file
    handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler('app.log', maxBytes=10240, backupCount=5)

    # set a custom log format, and add request
    # metadata to each log line
    handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(
         '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s '
         '[in %(filename)s:%(lineno)d] -- ip: %(clientip)s, '
         'url: %(url)s, method:%(method)s'))

    # the default log level is set to WARNING, so
    # we have to explictly set the logging level
    # to INFO to get our custom message logged.
    app.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    # append the handler to the default application logger
    app.logger.addHandler(handler)

    app.run(port=80, debug=True)
```

with this settings.py file

```
DOMAIN = {'people': {}}

# Please note that MONGO_HOST and MONGO_PORT could very well be left
# out as they already default to a bare bones local 'mongod' instance.
MONGO_HOST = 'localhost'
MONGO_PORT = 27017

# Skip this block if your db has no auth. But it really should.
# MONGO_USERNAME = '<your username>'
# MONGO_PASSWORD = '<your password>'
# Name of the database on which the user can be authenticated,
# needed if --auth mode is enabled.
# MONGO_AUTH_SOURCE = '<dbname>'

MONGO_DBNAME = 'DBNAME'

RESOURCE_METHODS = ['GET']
ITEM_METHODS = ['GET']

ALLOW_UNKNOWN = True
SERVER_NAME = None
```

I've also whitelisted HTTP port 80 for the network security group of the VM on Azure. I don't really know what else to do. When I send a GET request using Postman to http://VM.PUBLIC.IP/people the response is "Could not get any response". So for some reason the request never gets to the app. This is probably a simple thing but I'm new to everything I'm using here except Python itself. This app also works fine when everything is run locally.

Comment: Have you opened port 80 in your network security group?

Comment: Yes, in the incoming section @HongOoi

Comment: Things to check: (1) if you login to the VM and do a request to localhost, does it work? (2) if you run a simple web server (e.g. http.server) instead, does it work remotely? This will help you tell if the problem is on your VM, app, or in the connection from a remote host to your VM on port 80.

Comment: Running the server remotely and connecting on the remote with curl http://localhost/people works great. Something about my network settings are therefore wrong.